# Use of bit-torrent for large file download as an alternative to FTP

Tags: ftp, download, bittorrent

The company I work for procures large volumes of data and does this by subscribing to FTP locations. I was wondering if it is possible to download the same using a tracker, the major challenge is authentication of the users IMO. Most ftp servers we subscribe to have a restriction of the number of ftp connection attempts. Does any one here have any experience with this? Any advice is welcome.

***Edit***

To clarify, we subscribe to third party vendors and access their ftp location using credentials provided by them. The service is not exclusive to us, they do sell their data to several others. If we could be part of the swarm, the download rates would be pretty high without added penalty. The question is about the possibility of achieving this, so that we can put-forth a proposal in those lines. The vendors obviously wouldn't share data to non-subscribers, so that is a constraint.

Comment: Please clarify your question, especially what you mean by "subscribing to FTP".

Comment: @Pekka, Sounds to me like OP wants to redistribute bits they pull via ftp to clients via torrent.  Correct qeustzen? If so, fix the title and clarify the question for best results.

Comment: @questzen now I see. I'm deleting my answer.

Comment: I feel this is a gray area between serverfault and stackoverflow and was of two minds.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine the usual way would be setting up a BT Tracker, and establishing a source that starts distributing the material. I'm sure there will be better answers explaining how to do that, but [here](http://www.dessent.net/btfaq/#links) is what looks like a good starting point, outlining the installation of a Python based Tracker. I guess authentication is then a function within that setup.

What I really want to say though, Bittorrent also offer services tailor-made for applications like this: [Here](http://www.bittorrent.com/dna?csrc=splash) there are free and paid services, all promising to be much cheaper than a traditional Content Delivery Network. Can't say how secure it is though (in terms of the data being limited to a closed circle.)